# Arduino POST long JSON data

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, arduino, http-headers

I want to send dynamically sized (long) JSON data to a web API over an Ethernet module. Before sending the data, I have to send HTTP headers. My JSON data size is very big and I don't want to store this data in memory only to calculate the length of the data to send the `Content-Length` HTTP header. But I need to know this dynamically-created JSON data size to send the `Content-Length` HTTP header before sending the JSON data. Is there a way to send the JSON data without using Content-Type? Or do you have any other technique?

My sample Arduino code:

```
char output_buffer[100];
sprintf(output_buffer, "POST %s HTTP/1.1", url_path.c_str());
client.println(output_buffer);
sprintf(output_buffer, "Host: %s:%d", url_base.c_str(), port_number );
client.println("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
client.println("User-Agent: Fiddler");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();

for (byte index = 0; index < device_count; index++) {
  client.println("...");
  client.println("...");
  client.println("...");
  client.println("...");
}
```

This dynamically created JSON data length is approximately 15K.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding